# Memory Warning on the device, not with Instruments

Tags: ios, restkit, instruments, didreceivememorywarning

I have a huge synchronization process in which I download and unzip 400-500 `XML` files and then parse it. With this data Im going to create a lot of core data objects over the `RestKit API`. At the beginning, I had a memory warning with live bytes of 450mb+ because I did not using autorelease pools and only tried to save core data on the end.

I fixed that, saving now frequently to core data and using  `@autoreleasepool` blocks. When im running my app now with instruments, I can see how the live bytes only being 20mb-30mb, always releasing memory and never going to size up. The process just works. But when I start the app without instruments, after a view files I get a `Memory Warning`. Later on the app crashs.

What is the differene between running the app with and without the `instruments` tool? Why does it end in different results?

Comment: One difference is that usually profiling with Instruments causes a release build to be made, while running through Xcode causes a debug build to be made.  Not sure how this could affect this situation though.

Comment: Eg you could have Zombies enabled in the debug config but not the Release config

Comment: guys - I just LOVE this platform. I just did not know that instruments is using the release build. Because my objects are that large the zombie enabled was a fail. When im using the release build everything is working like a charm. Pls give it as an answer so that I can accept it. You dont know how much it helped me. Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm adding this answer because I'm so happy that I came across this page.

What *@borrrden* suggested is partially true. You can configure which Build settings it will use when you profile. To configure this, goto Xcode and open the Edit Scheme dialog and select in the left menu *Profile XXX.app*. You will see you can choose a Build Configuration (either Debug or Release).

[image]

What *@hooleyhoop* commented was more crucial to find the solution. Even if your Profile Build Configuration is set to Debug, there is still a difference between Profiling and a default Run from within Xcode. You can specify *Diagnostics* in the *Run* section. Right there, there is an option called *Enable Zombie Objects* under *Memory Management*. Make sure that this option is **unchecked**.

[image]

These diagnostic Run settings are not used while profiling. That is the explanation for the behavior you are experiencing. There isn't a Diagnostics tab on the Profile section as well.

---

The result is that my game (Gump) crashed after 5 minutes of doing nothing in the main menu with *Zombie Objects* enabled. Once I disabled *Zombie Objects*, my game runs as far as I know for an infinite amount of time. After 45 minutes, still no Memory Warnings.

Comment: That's because enabling Zombies leaks all objects on purpose to be able to track when sending messages to dead objects.

Comment: Okay, that is why. I wasn't sure. Thanks for that. I think it is something that might be forgotten easily that it is still turned on.